# Symfony 5.4, Doctrine, Docker: Why need to use 2 Database connections

Tags: php, docker, symfony, doctrine

I have the following question. I am not able to connect database to my project. For instance, when I want to create new database, insert new table, I need to use the following database connection

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:55000/symfonyproject?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11&charset=utf8mb4"
```

But to retrieve, and display some data from database, I need to use this connection. As soon as I use the first one, I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]`

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@db:3306/symfonyproject?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11&charset=utf8mb4"
```

As soon I use first connection to retrieve information, I get error that the connection is not possible. I am using symfony 5.4 on ddev(docker) machine.

```
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Comment: I would assume that the docker setup is quite important to answer this one, the connection strings look fine so far.

Comment: @Jakumi Indeed. Because both of the connections work, but not how I want. I always need to switch connections for certain tasks. Especially now, when I create CI/CD PIpeline to include phpunit. Need to use 2 connections, which is not possible lol

Comment: maybe my comment was too subtle. show your docker configs... docker-compose, etc. ;o) (on an additional note: it's actually a bit hard to handle two different database connections simultaneously. it has been done, but it's a bit annoying ;o/ see for example https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: I actually figured out. To create database, tables etc. I need to be inside docker container, otherwise wont work. As well I solved at the end of the day, to run phpunit, and to connecto the the server (here was the problem that I used mysql for host instead 127.0.0.1). Anyways, thanks for you help! :)